# How to generate in opencv 64 bit libnative_camera .so files in Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake, android-ndk

I have build opencv through cmake in linux, I have successfully generated shared_library.so files but also wants to generate these .so files as well.

```
libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so
libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so
libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
```

I have successfully generated these .so files:-

```
libopencv_calib3d.so
libopencv_core.so
libopencv_dnn.so
libopencv_imgproc.so
libopencv_ml.so
libopencv_objdetect.so
libopencv_videoio.so
```

I have run below command to get above so files.

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/chetu/AndroidWork/android-ndk-r17c/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NDK=/home/chetu/AndroidWork/android-ndk-r17c -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=OFF -DANDROID_STL=c++_shared -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_opencv_androidcamera=ON -DBUILD_OPENCV_NATIVECAMERA=ON -DBUILD_opencv_calib3d=ON -DBUILD_opencv_core=ON -DBUILD_opencv_core=ON -DBUILD_opencv_features2d=ON -DBUILD_opencv_flann=ON -DBUILD_opencv_highgui=ON -DBUILD_opencv_imgproc=ON -DBUILD_opencv_video=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/chetu/OpenCv/opencv-2.4.11/android_build/out -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a
```

Please help me I am new in Android development.